# how to execute batch file after successful server side SSH connection in Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, notifications, windows-10, openssh

I would like to setup a SSH Server on my PC and access it from Internet but I would like to be notified on each SSH successful connection (maybe on fail too in order to check if there no Bruteforce attack). I'm using OpenSSH-Win64 but I can't see any option to execute a batch file to make a CURL call. I saw that on Linux it is possible to use ForceCommand but the command seems not to work on Windows.
I tried to add this on the end of the file sshd_config file :

```
ForceCommand C:/tools/send_sms.bat
```

send_sms.bat :

```
curl --header "Access-Token: <myToken>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "{\"data\":{\"addresses\":[\"<myPhoneNumber>\"],\"message\":\"Someone successfully connected with SSH\",\"target_device_iden\":\"<myDeviceId>\"}}" --request POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/texts
```

but nothing happen on successful connection although the bat works on manual execution.
I could watch C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs\sshd.log file but it's a little bit tricky.
Does someone have any solution/idea?
Thank you

Comment: What is the content of the batch file? There are a few things that could happen here, but impossible without seeing the batch file.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should ask questions like this on [sf] or [su].

Comment: batch file just content a CURL call to Pushbullet API. I edited my question so you can check.

Doesn't Stackoverflow help with scripting too? Anyway thank you for your advice I will post there too.